# Geotools Point in Polygon incorrect result vs QGIS

Tags: qgis, java, geotools

I need to find the point in a polygon to get the corresponding feature and the result does not match the display in QGIS. QGIS shows the information correctly but with geotools I can't get it right.

Code:

```
public Map<String, String> getLocalityRecognizer(double lat, double lng) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException {

    Map<String, String> nombreCordon = new HashMap<String, String>();

    FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> shapeSource = getShapeFeatures();

    while (shapeSource.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = shapeSource.next();

        //This fragment return the result
        if (feature.getBounds().contains(lat, lng)) {
            nombreCordon.put("localidad", Normalizer.normalize(feature.getAttribute("nombre").toString().toLowerCase(), Form.NFC));
            nombreCordon.put("cordon", feature.getAttribute("cordon").toString());

            return nombreCordon;
        }
    }

    shapeSource.close();

    return null;
}

private FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> getShapeFeatures() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException {
    File shpFile = new File("C://Users//Sdev//Documents//shp//voys_meli.shp");

    // Read
    DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder
            .getDataStore(Collections.singletonMap("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL()));

    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource("voys_meli");

    FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> inputFeatureCollection = 
            new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(source.getFeatures(), CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));


    return inputFeatureCollection.features();
}
```

With the same point, the code returns "MERLO", but the point intersect "ITUZAINGO".

[image]

CRS is EPSG:4326

**SOLUTION**

```
    while (shapeSource.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature feature = shapeSource.next();

        MultiPolygon geo = (MultiPolygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

        GeometryFactory fac = new GeometryFactory();

        Point p = fac.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lng));

        if (geo.contains(p)) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if the point intersects the bounding box of the polygons. You may want to use the true geometry instead

```
if (feature.getBounds().contains(lat, lng)) {
```

should become

```
if (feature.contains(lat, lng)) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution is as follows, thank you very much for opening my head.

   MultiPolygon geo = (MultiPolygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
   
   GeometryFactory fac = new GeometryFactory();
   
   Point p = fac.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lng));
   
   if (geo.contains(p)) {}

Answer (score 2):

Easier and more idiomatic is to do:

```
    GeometryFactory fac = new GeometryFactory();
    FilterFactory2 filterFactory = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(GeoTools
            .getDefaultHints());
    FeatureCollection features = featureSource.getFeatures();
    Expression propertyName = filterFactory.property(features.getSchema()
            .getGeometryDescriptor().getName());
    Filter filter = filterFactory.contains(propertyName,
            filterFactory.literal(p));
    SimpleFeatureCollection sub = features.subCollection(filter);
```

Then `sub` will contain any or all of the polygons that contain the point, (and if your datastore is "smart" it will have used a spatial index to exclude features that can't contain your point).

PS - take care to always close your `FeatureIterator`s with a `finally` block, as written you never close yours if a feature is found.